# Freeze columns after move

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I would like to freeze two columns after I move them.

ex: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsiali_sixmon/y8dxfwhy/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=y8dxfwhy)

```
var
    myData = Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(10, 50),
    container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot;

hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: myData,
    rowHeaders: false,
    colHeaders: true,
    preventOverflow: 'horizontal',
    allowInsertRow: false,
    allowInsertColumn: false,
    fixedColumnsLeft: 2,
    contextMenu: false,
    manualColumnMove: [2, 5],
    manualColumnFreeze: true
});
```

But it's possible to move them again after manually...

How can I block the manual move after I move them in option ?

Or just freeze the fixed column ?

Thanks guys ;)

Comment: manualColumnFreeze property is for that . I see that you have already used it.

Comment: Yes but you can already move the first and second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find how to freeze column, but the guide is always displaying.

Solution : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsiali_sixmon/f8p5aLje/)

```
var
   myData = Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(10, 50),
   container = document.getElementById('example1'),
   hot,
   fixedColumnsLeft = 2;

hot = new Handsontable(container, {
   data: myData,
   rowHeaders: false,
   colHeaders: true,
   preventOverflow: 'horizontal',
   allowInsertRow: false,
   allowInsertColumn: false,
   fixedColumnsLeft: fixedColumnsLeft,
   contextMenu: false,
   manualColumnMove: true,
   manualColumnFreeze: true,
   beforeColumnMove: setBeforeColumnMove(),
});

function setBeforeColumnMove() {
   return function(startColumn, endColumn) {
      var manualColumnMove = hot.getPlugin("ManualColumnMove");

      if (startColumn < fixedColumnsLeft || endColumn < fixedColumnsLeft) {
         manualColumnMove.changeColumnPositions(endColumn, startColumn);
      }
   }
};
```